# Netezza error store procedure error

Tags: database, netezza

I try to execute a stored procedure and I have the following issue.
I don't know if I have a problem with the format of the string.
This is my error message:

> ERROR:  unexpected error 12 in EXECUTE of query 'MERGE INTO GTN..ON_ORDER_REPORT_TSS_TEST a
>       USING QUANTISENSE_PROD_STAGE..VW_CURRENT_VIEW_OF_LINE_SHEET_HIST b
>       ON TRIM(a.channel) = TRIM(upper(b.channel_desc))
>       and TRIM(a.style_colour) = TRIM(b.style_opt_numb)
>       and TRIM(a.season_code) = TRIM(b.season_cd)
>       and a.STYLE_COLOUR = 'IG1501S-034121'
>       WHEN MATCHED THEN
>       UPDATE SET a.REVISED_IN_STORE_DT = b.REVISED_IN_STORE_DT || ' 00:00:00', 
>              a.PLANNED_IN_STORE_DT = b.PLANNED_IN_STORE_DT || ' 00:00:00';'

This is the code of my stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE USP_UPDATE_LINE_SHEET_TEST(CHARACTER VARYING(ANY))
RETURNS CHARACTER VARYING(ANY)
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE 
TABLENAME ALIAS FOR $1; 
SQL TEXT;
SQLFULL varchar(4000);

BEGIN 
SQL := 'MERGE INTO GTN..'||TABLENAME||' a 
USING QUANTISENSE_PROD_STAGE..VW_CURRENT_VIEW_OF_LINE_SHEET_HIST b 
ON TRIM(a.channel) = TRIM(upper(b.channel_desc)) 
and TRIM(a.style_colour) = TRIM(b.style_opt_numb) 
and TRIM(a.season_code) = TRIM(b.season_cd) 
and a.STYLE_COLOUR = ''IG1501S-034121''
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET a.REVISED_IN_STORE_DT = b.REVISED_IN_STORE_DT || '' 00:00:00'', 
       a.PLANNED_IN_STORE_DT = b.PLANNED_IN_STORE_DT || '' 00:00:00'';';           
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SQL;    
END; 
END_PROC;
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: Please properly format your question, it's hard to tell where the code starts and what's part of your text: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting